# May/might had done

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs, perfect-constructions

We can use the structure “**may/might have done**” to talk about what was possible to happen or the past possibilities:

> *You might have left your cellphone at work*. = Perhaps you have left your cellphone at work.

I wonder if we can use a similar structure for the past. For example:

> *I could not find my cellphone. I might had left it at work.* = Perhaps I had left it at work.

I have just seen the first structure in my grammar textbook but not the second one. Can we use the structure “**might had done**”, like in the second example?

Comment: The second example needs the same tense as the first: "I might ***have*** left it at work" and "Perhaps I left it at work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure 'might had' is ungrammatical. If you are using a modal auxiliary verb (might, may, could, etc) to express something in the past, it has to be in the format `have + past participle`.

> I **might have passed** the exam if I had studied a harder.
> You **might have said** something that made him angry.
> He **may have been** at the party, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 2):

***may* and *might* take the bare infinitive of the verb that follows**

I may [to] go  ---> I may go

I might [to] go ---> I might go

I may [to] have Covid 19 ---> I may have Covid 19

I might [to] have Covid 19 ---> I might have Covid 19

I may [to] have gone ---> I may have gone

I might [to] have gone ---> I might have gone

---

**No English verbs have a simple-past infinitive**

You can say "to say". You cannot say "to had".

<strike>I may [to] had gone</strike> --->  <strike>I may had gone</strike>.

<strike>I might [to] had gone</strike> ---> <strike>I might had gone</strike>